# Getting Spring MVC to work with JodaModule

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, jodatime

This is a little frustrating... I had this working before in my previous projects, but unable to get it working in my new project after debugging for several hours.

Let's assume I have a simple Rest controller that returns Joda's `LocalDate`:-

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public final class ApiController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<LocalDate> main() {
        return new ResponseEntity<LocalDate>(LocalDate.now(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

By default, when I call `http://app/api`, I get `[2015,10,13]`. What I really want is `2015-10-13`.

To solve this in my previous project, I got it working with this configuration in `spring-servlet.xml`:-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>

    <context:component-scan base-package="test.controller"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="objectMapper"
          class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean"
          p:indentOutput="true"
          p:simpleDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ">
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
          p:targetObject-ref="objectMapper"
          p:targetMethod="registerModule">
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"/>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
</beans>
```

But, when I do the same thing in my new project, I'm getting `[2015,10,13]` again instead of `2015-10-13`.

I did upgrade some dependencies and I also make sure there's no additional `ObjectMapper` being loaded.

Here's my current dependency tree... I removed all the things that I don't need:-

[image]

How do I configure Spring MVC to return the correct date format in JSON?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `<mvc:annotation-driven>` twice. Try removing the first declaration (empty, default config). Probably the message converter you configured in the second `<mvc:annotation-driven>` is getting overriden by the first declaration (with default message converters).

Comment: My goodness.... you are absolutely right, and somehow I didn't even notice that. Thank you.